# AVPlayer unable to play video on IPV6 network

Tags: ios, networking, avplayer, ipv6, ipv4

Ours is ipv4 network. We play all our videos on AVPlayer on this network; all these videos work fine. After our app got rejected by Apple, we have setup ipv6 network. Surprisingly, no video is able to play on ipv6!

I am not sure where to start from. Does it have to do something with the way I am making a backend call? or is it something entirely different?

I am sorry if my question sounds naive. I am new to networking and would appreciate any pointers.

EDIT 1: I realized that some videos are working but they are taking a lot of time, like 10-30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Your server need to support iPV6, for this you need to add iPV6 Compatability, Please check url it complusary to have domain configured on ipv6
[Apple Guide lines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
check section 2.5.5 
Test ur domain [here](http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php)

EDIT: If it is video problem then Show Loading with a proper message before loading video.

Comment: Hey - I realized that some videos are working but they are taking a lot of time, like 1 min - 1.5 minutes. Will you answer change on the basis of this?

Comment: Your Server should support IPV6 , I got the same issue but it was solved by adding IPV6 Support.

Comment: Our server does support IPV6 because I am able to play the same video from web browser